# Syntax - defining range when your rows are variables

Tags: vba, excel

I am brand new to vba. I need help with some more complex syntax.

I have two nested loops that are compare the contents of certain rows to the contents of every other row. The "current row count" is stored in integers curRow and iterateRow

**How do I copy/paste the contents of iterate row from column E to the last column containing text?**

This is what I have

```
Dim lastIterateCol As Long
Dim lastCurCol As Long
Dim copyRange As Range

lastCurCol = ws.Cells(curRow, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastIterateCol = ws.Cells(iterateRow, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

//this next portion is what I'm struggling with
ws.Range("E" & iterateRow + ":" + CStr(lastIterateCol) & iterateRow).Copy

ws.Cells(curRow, lastCurCol).Paste
ws.Rows(iterateRow).EntireRow.Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `lastIterateCol` is numeric, use this form

```
ws.Range(ws.Range("E" & iterateRow), ws.Cells(iterateRow, lastIterateCol)).Copy
```